# Display user image ({{ userprofile.image.url }}) on my base.html

Tags: python, django

I hope you're well? I'm beginner with Django. I'm using a profile for my users (witch belongs to "User" folder. I'd like to display the image on my base.html (witch belongs to "Nutriscore" "templates" folder). How I can do it? {{ userprofile.image.url }} only works on my update_profile.html page (witch belongs to the user templates folder).

MonProjetDjango

- Nutriscore
  -- templates (base.html)
  -- urls.py
- User
  -- templates
  -- views.py
  -- models.py

User > views.py

```
@method_decorator(login_required(login_url='login/'),name="dispatch")
class UserProfileUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = UserProfile
    template_name = 'profile-update.html'
    form_class = UserProfileForm
    success_message = "Profile updated"


    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.save()
        return super(UserProfileUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('update_profile',kwargs={'slug':self.object.slug})
    
    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        if self.object.user != request.user:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        
        return super(UserProfileUpdateView, self).get(request,*args,**kwargs)
```

User > models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    street = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=300)
    number_street = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=20)
    street_detail = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=300)
    town = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=60)
    zipcode = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=20)
    country = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=60)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True,default='user/user-128.png', upload_to='user/')
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False)
    
    def save(self, *args,**kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.user.username)
        super(UserProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        if img.height > 200 or img.width > 200:
            new_size = (200, 200)
            img.thumbnail(new_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
            
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
        
def create_user_profile(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
        
post_save.connect(create_user_profile,sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

Nutriscore > urls.py

```
path('profile/<slug:slug>/', UserProfileUpdateView.as_view(), name="update_profile"),
```

I'd like to display this in my base.html

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %} <a href="/profile/{{ user.username }}" class="button-login">{{ userprofile.image.url }} Hello {{ user.username }}</a> {% else %} <a href="/login/" class="button-login">Login</a> {% endif %}
```

Comment: Where's your base.html file,show it and why do you want your user profile image showing in the base.html

Comment: thanks for your answer :) My base.html is in Nutriscore folder (templates folder). Because I'd like to show this:
            {% if user.is_authenticated %} <a href="/profile/{{ user.username }}" class="button-login"><img src="{{ userprofile.image.url }}"> Hello {{ user.username }}</a> {% else %} <a href="https://nutri.feedcool.fr/login/" class="button-login">Login</a> {% endif %}

Comment: Just use <img src="{{ user.userprofile.image.url }}">, user here refers to the user making the http request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your want to get the image of the user making the request  then use the user keyword in the sense that for every user making a request , django automatically load the user object properties so use this to get the img

```
  {{user.userprofile.image.url}}
```